# Custom captcha displaying wrong numbers

Tags: php

I am creating a custom captcha and it works well, but sometimes it will choose a random number from `$rand_keys` that is greater than the number of boxes displayed.  How do I fix this?

```
$color = array("red", "blue", "yellow", "white", "green", "purple", "brown", "orange", "pink", "black");
$random_num_box = mt_rand(3,8);

$numbers=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$rand_keys = array_rand($numbers, $random_num_box);
$ran_box =  mt_rand(0, $random_num_box);

echo "Random number of boxes:  ".$random_num_box."<br /><br />";
echo "<div>";
foreach ($rand_keys as $k=>$v) {
    echo "<div style='width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; margin-right: 2px; display: inline-block; background: ".$color[$numbers[$v]].";'></div>";
}
echo "</div>";

echo "<br />What is the color of box # ". ($ran_box + 1) ."?";
echo "<br />Answer:  ".$color[$rand_keys[$ran_box]];
```

Comment: seems to be working fine... can't seem to generate what you are saying

Comment: Keep trying it.  You will get a question that has no answer.  It will pick a number greater than the number of boxes.

Comment: You're right! I submitted an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that occasionally you get a randomly picked number larger than the amount of boxes displayed. This seems to originate from the following two lines:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($numbers, $random_num_box);
$ran_box =  mt_rand(0, $random_num_box);
```

Since this is hard to simulate, due to being random, the easiest way is to figure an example that proves that it does not work.

From research, you will find that `array_rand` will take an array and randomly select the amount of items based on the second argument, in this case `$random_num_box`. So we have the following array:

```
array(
 [0] => 1,
 [1] => 2,
 [2] => 3
)
```

Now we move on to get the random answer (`$ran_box`). The arguments will be (for this example) `$random_num_box = 3;` So the command running is

```
$ran_box =  mt_rand(0, 3);
```

You will get a value between 0 and 3 (including). Due to your array only being a size of 3 (0->2), you will get an error when your random number is 3 (or `$random_num_box`). This is due to trying to access `array[3]` which does not exist.

To fix this, you must make the max value 1 less.

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($numbers, $random_num_box);
$ran_box =  mt_rand(0, $random_num_box - 1);
```

Comment: I'll check out your answer soon.  Sorry, got really busy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to substract 1 from `$ran_box`

```
$ran_box =  mt_rand(0, $random_num_box-1);
```

Comment: Suggestion: Do not answer questions with "I think" as it makes it more of a comment then an answer. Also, backup your answers with facts or an explanation as to why so the readers can understand why this is an answer to the problem.

Comment: Sorry, busy right now.  I'll get back to try this out asap.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You both had the same answer, but his was first.